# How do I check mysql user have privileges like root user

Tags: c++, mysql, privileges

I use mysql c++ wrapper in client side to connect to mysql server. When user establishes connection to mysql server I want to know whether the user have privileges like root (i.e. `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION`).
The `SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER` query gives grants for current user, but i need to parse the string and compare to know whether the current user have privileges like root. I am looking for an alternative options.

Comment: mind to **grant** some of your question answers?

Answer (score 0):

You could query the various tables in mysql.* and compare the permissions fields between the accounts. Of course, you'd have to account for variances in the host/user fields, as MySQL considers root@localhost to be a completely different account than root@% and root@10.0.0.1 etc..

select * from mysql.TABLE where User in ('root', 'youraccount', 'someotheraccount');

where TABLE is 'user', 'db', 'func', etc...

Comment: This is definetely easier to parse than SHOW GRANTS, but you need read access to the mysql database - which may or may not be a drawback.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just perform a test action that would only be able to be accomplished by a 'root' superuser.. and if it fails you're out of luck, but if it works, you'd be in business?